# Is there a way to advance through a for loop by a value instead of one by one in VBScript?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a one dimensional array in VBScript that I would like to run through but have the ability to advance by 2,3,4 etc. on each iteration of the loop.  In C this would be trivial as...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+= 2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
For i = 0 To 9 Step 2
```

Comment: Yeh that's the stuff.  Thanks!